# IOS Phonegap - text on a background color becomes double worded

Tags: ios, css, cordova, webkit

On my iphone phonegap app, whenever I've got text on a background color, the text seems to get a ghosting effect, the same text is repeated 2 or 3 pixels below, almost like a drop shadow but exactly below and in the same color as the text.

Any ideas how to get rid of this? I'm guessing its applying some kind of -webkit specific styling but I can't seem to find what it is.

Below is an image of what is happening, the text to the left, 'Web Deal' is the problem, whereas the text on the right is fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to fix this, it was picking up a text-shadow property from jquery mobile css. It was applying it to all text but because its white it was only visible on text with a background colour. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please post your css.

If you are able to open the app on Chrome browser on a desktop, try inspect element and you can find which styles are applied to the text.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide any CSS I'll just assume that your text ist rendered bold.
Rendering bold type in mobile Safari or the WebView is buggy and causes the weird effect.

Try using a text-shadow instead.

```
.bold {
  //font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix this, it was picking up a text-shadow property from jquery mobile css. It was applying it to all text but because its white it was only visible on text with a background colour. Thankis for your help